# Cannot play m3u8 streams with WPFMediakit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, streaming, media-player

Hello can anyone managed to play m3u8 streams with WpfMediakit? Whatever Url I am setting it always gives me the same error: Could not render any streams from the source Uri.

I am sure the streams are working becaouse I can play them with my UWP app's media element control which supports that kind of streams. Is this an issue or I am doing something wrong? Here is my code:

```
    private void MediaPlayer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaPlayer.LoadedBehavior = WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.MediaPlayers.MediaState.Manual;
        MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(
            @"Some Uri that ends with m3u8",
            UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        MediaPlayer.Play();
    }

<controls:MediaUriElement
            x:Name="MediaPlayer"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Loaded="MediaPlayer_Loaded"
            Stretch="Fill"
            MediaFailed="MediaPlayer_MediaFailed"/>
```

I am subscribed to MediaFailed event which fires twice. First time it gives me: Could not render any streams from the source Uri. Second time is object reference not set error. I cannot figure out which object since there is not any indication.

The usage of WPFMediaKit is not a necessity if there is a better control I could use it except VLCDotNet. Any help is greatly appriciated.